# Change ViewModel when checkbox is selected (or not)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

guys!

I have this ViewModel:

```
public class ItemViewModel {
    [Display(Name="Has serie number?")]
    public bool HasSerieNumber { get; set; }
    public string SerieNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I have this View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(item => item.HasSerieNumber);
@Html.CheckBoxFor(item => item.HasSerieNumber);

@Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.SerieNumber);
```

And this JS code:

```
$('#HasSerieNumber').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#SerieNumber').show();   
    } else {
        $('#SerieNumber').hide();
    }
});
```

Well, the SerieNumber textbox is shown when I check HasSerieNumber checkbox.
Is there a way to fire/change HasSerieNumber property when I checked the item in the View?
The idea is: when I checked the checkbox, the value of property will be changed and I can control the visibility of the textbox thru this property.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because the `HasSerieNumber` property is bound to the checkbox your code already does that. When the checkbox is checked the `HasSerieNumber` will be sent as `true` to the corresponding controller action and when unchecked it will be `false`. You are also effectively toggling the visibility of the corresponding textbox when the checkbox is clicked.

So just wrap this in a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController"))
{

    @Html.LabelFor(item => item.HasSerieNumber)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => item.HasSerieNumber)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.SerieNumber)

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and when the form is submitted to the following controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(ItemViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

the model will be correctly bound from the request values thanks to the default model binder - the `HasSerieNumber` and `SerieNumber` properties will contain the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Darin. I know this. My doubt is: is there a way to fire some Controller method in the moment I click in the checkbox? My code works perfectly, I just want to know if I can fire some Controller method on clicking the checkbox. Thanks!